# How to draw on google map when google map fragment is not visible

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a question about google map and fragment. In particular I would like to know how to update (drawing a marker or path) on map when map fragment is not visible.

In fragment activity I implemented locationlistener. I have different fragments. In on of the fragments I'm showing google map. When location changes I draw a marker and path on the map if the google map fragment is visible (I implement interface). I want to know how can I update my map when map fragment is not visible.

One way I did this is that in the onCreate method I create SupportMapFragment to get the google map reference and then I update this map if googlemap fragment is not visible.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    mapfm = MySupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    map = mapfm.getMap();
 }



 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    ...

    LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                       location.getLongitude());

    if (map != null) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng));
    }
}
```

Is there any better way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: not visible as in the fragment does not exist or not visible as in you set the visibility to `INVISIBLE`?

Comment: I just swipe to other fragment. So I can't see a map. Fragment still exists.